# Check if argument is correct in OCMVerify

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

In OCMock there is the method `OCMVerify` to verify interactions. So I did the following with `MyObjectData` being a simple value holder class.

```
OCMVerify([dataStore createOrUpdateMyObject:[OCMArg isKindOfClass:[MyObjectData class]]]);
```

This works, but is not enough, since I want to verify that the method isn't called with any object of this class but with the correct values. So I did the following:

```
// ...

    OCMVerify([dataStore createOrUpdateMyObject:[OCMArg checkWithSelector:@selector(verifyMyObjectDataAfterSave:) onObject:self]]);
}

- (BOOL)verifyMyObjectDataAfterSave:(id)obj {
    return YES;
}
```

But the `obj` parameter is not the `MyObjectData` instance I expect to be passed but an instance of `OCMVerifier` which is a proxy to the mocked data store.

Now the question is, how can I verify the argument correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use an expectation?

```
id mockObj = OCMPartialMock(dataStore);
OCMExpect([mockObj createOrUpdateMyObject:[OCMArg checkWithBlock:^BOOL(MyObjectData *value)
                                           {
                                               XCTAssertEqual(value.someProperty, 999);
                                               return [value isKindOfClass:[MyObjectData class]];
                                           }]]);
[mockObj someMethod];
OCMVerifyAll(mockObj);
```